# Failure access Feeds, Private Blog on Blogger

Tags: blogger, feed

How can I resolve the problem of failure to access the feeds on Private Blog Blogger?
I need to show recent comments. thank you

Comment: Site feeds don't work when the blog is set to Private. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698909/using-jsonp-to-create-blogger-site-getting-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on/48699003#48699003

Comment: if I add a Post feed redirect URL?
it could be a solution?

Comment: If the blog is already private & you try to generate a Feedburner feed, that will fail(Refer to https://i.imgur.com/Yj9BWSv.png). If you have previously created a Feedburner feed & later turned the blog into a Private one, then new posts will not be synced with that feed. Mainly, if you want to access feeds when the blog is Private (either only accessible to Blog authors or specific email addresses) you will have to use Blogger type feed URLs(like https://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default) which will only work when you are logged into the Google account to which the access is granted

Comment: the url you suggested works for posts:
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/8662182510704392699/posts/default

but for comments does not allow access or I have wrong syntax? 
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/8662182510704392699/comments/default

Comment: The comment Feed URL is correct but the issue is that the global comment feed is disabled for Private Blogs (even the blogger.com URL). But individual post's comment feed still functions (like https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOGID/POSTID/comments/default/)